# AWS Glue Catalog unable to detect parquet files, creates root path as a single table instead

Tags: amazon-web-services, parquet, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I've a list of 500+ tables stored in AWS S3 in parquet format. The structure is as follows:

```
aws-bucket/
└── parquet/
    └── table1/t1.parquet
    └── table2/t2.parquet
    └── table3/t3.parquet
    └── table4/t4.parquet
    └── table5/t5.parquet
    └── table6/t6.parquet
    └── table7/t7.parquet
    └── table8/t8.parquet
```

When I run a Glue Crawler on "s3://aws-bucket/parquet/", and try to create an Athena DB, it only creates a table called parquet, instead of creating all 500+ tables. I haven't tried with any customization on the crawler parameters.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Check https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/crawler-configuration.html?icmpid=docs_glue_console#crawler-grouping-policy

Grouping behavior for S3 data (optional)

**Create a single schema for each S3 path**

*By default, when a crawler defines tables for data stored in S3, it considers both data compatibility and schema similarity. Select this check box to group compatible schemas into a single table definition across all S3 objects under the provided include path. Other criteria will still be considered to determine proper grouping.*

Check this option in glue crawler console. It will create 500+ tables

Comment: I already tried that option my friend, it doesn't work too. It creates the same parquet table in Athena DB and with more, much more number of columns (probably took columns from every table). This is the error: Your query has the following error(s):

HIVE_INVALID_METADATA: Hive metadata for table parquet is invalid: Table descriptor contains duplicate columns

Comment: Most like it contains same name for two columns. Are you getting error while creating tables through crawler or while running query in athena? I believe it is second one. Share schema from glue catalog for further analysis

Comment: The second case, no doubts. Is there a programmatic way of adding multiple S3 sources to a specific crawler? If so, then I can run a Lambda function to get full path of all objects in that location and pass them onto the crawler as separate sources. I see very less clarity in the documentation for this kind of scenario, similarly there's less tutorial videos on the same.

Comment: Only include and exclude pattern is possible. You cant add multiple s3 sources in crawler

Comment: You can add S3 as a data store. You can add as many S3 paths using "add another Data Store" as you wish. Was thinking if I can build the list of all table paths using AWS Lambda function, python code.

Comment: Unless more details are provided to reproduce issue, I won't be able to help. You may try with lambda but my guess is you may still face same error

Comment: Challenge is it is confidential data, hard to reproduce. And there is no error when I am doing folder by folder manually (fullpath/table1/, fullpath/table2/, etc). It only fails when I give the path till one directory back which contain all folders. Meaning, no issue with data or schema, only that the crawler needs some more input to segregate tables inside the folder parquet (I know its all object in S3 and no actual folder/directory as such).

Comment: As per https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/glue-best-practices.html#schema-crawlers-data-sources, it seems your proposal ""add another Data Store"  is the only option for you.  It seems for parquet format, somehow it throws 'HIVE_INVALID_METADATA' error

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because your parquet files have the same schema, you can try with table level configuration. In your case, you can configure crawler to create table at level 3, which will create tables at `table1, 2, 3...` level.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/crawler-configuration.html#crawler-table-level